# I changed the php 7.4 version to php 8.1 in cPanel. Now facing issue of "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON

Tags: codeigniter

I changed the php 7.4 version to php 8.1 in cPanel. Now facing issue of Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 109 (line 2 column 1) at JSON.parse () at cart.js:279:29 for code:
`postData(endpoint, params, (response) => {` 
`response = JSON.parse(response);`
`if (response.state) {`
`getCartProducts();`

Comment: How and where are you getting this error? What version of CI are you using? please add mre details.

Comment: I used the CodeIgniter 3. In cart.js file I got this error while running the ecommerce website after changing php version to php 8.1